# Is non-equivalence of regular expressions with union, concatenation and squaring NEXPTIME-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-expressions

On wikipedia, page about EXPSPACE it says

> An example of an EXPSPACE-complete problem is the problem of recognizing whether two regular expressions represent different languages, where the expressions are limited to four operators: union, concatenation, the Kleene star (zero or more copies of an expression), and squaring (two copies of an expression).[1]
> If the Kleene star is left out, then that problem becomes NEXPTIME-complete..."

A proof of the EXPSPACE-completeness can be found in the referenced paper, but there is no reference to the NEXPTIME-completeness, and the proof of EXPSPACE-hardness from the paper does not seem to be applicable to the case with no kleene star (at least I dont see how it would apply, as the proof requires construction of an infinite language which is not possible withouth kleene star). I tried searching for a proof of the NEXPTIME-completeness, but was unable to find any results pertaining to this problem, everything I found assumed kleene star. So my questions are the following

1. Is the stated problem with no kleene star indeed NEXPTIME-hard?
2. How is the NEPTIME-hardness obtained?

A reference to some paper pertaining said problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE. I tagged the offending statement with “citation needed”, as such a claim needs a proper reference, or it should go. (It was already present in the original version of the article as created by user “LC”, who has not been active since 2002, so there is no chance to ask them for a source.)

Comment: If your question elicits no response in a couple of weeks, consider reasking it at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com.